# MQ Input/Output count increasing when Datapower client is connect using MQ front side handler

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

I am using MQ 7.5.0.2 and Datapower client IDG7

When MQ send messages to Datapower, Datapower receive those messages using MQ front side handlers and also same way it do send messages using Backend URL
But the problem I am facing it when ever Datapower connects to MQ, Queue Input/Output count increases to (10 ~20) and remains same and the Handle state is INACTIVE.
When I see queue details using below commands it is displaying as below

```
 display qstatus(******) type(handle)

   QUEUE(********)                      TYPE(HANDLE)
   APPLDESC(WebSphere MQ Channel)
   APPLTAG(WebSphere Datapower MQClient)
   APPLTYPE(SYSTEM)                        BROWSE(NO)
   CHANNEL(*****)                             CONNAME(******)
   ASTATE(NONE)                            HSTATE(INACTIVE)
   INPUT(SHARED)                           INQUIRE(NO)
   OUTPUT(NO)                              PID(25391)
   QMURID(0.1149)                         SET(NO)
   TID(54)
   URID(XA_FORMATID[] XA_GTRID[] XA_BQUAL[])
   URTYPE(QMGR)
```

Can any one help me in this.It only clearing when ever i restart the queue manager but I dont want to restart the qmgr every time.

Answer (score 1):

HSTATE in INACTIVE state indicates "No API call from a connection is currently in progress for this object. For a queue, this condition can arise when no MQGET WAIT call is in progress.". This is likely to happen if the application(DP in this case) opened the queue and then not issuing any API calls on the opened object. Pid 25391 - is this for an amqrmppa process? Is DP expected to consume messages on this queue continuously?

Comment: Yes DP meant to Pool messages on that queue for every 30 seconds.But When I send messages again it is creating more OpenInput Count to the existing ones.

Comment: I suspect this could be problem with DP. Could you please check with DP support if there is any known problems fixed on the DP side, particularly repeatedly opening the queue. It is also worth checking if the number of connections from DP is also increasing.