# DataPower MQ Connection count reached max limit

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

We are getting this error in every alternate day.I know that increasing the channel max depth will resolve the issue. Is there any option we could close the connection after the messages have been pushed to the queues? Can we do that in that way?

Comment: Looks like the Client in DataPower is not closing connections to queue manager. It is opening connection repeatedly but not closing it once the job is done. Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265915/mq-input-output-count-increasing-when-datapower-client-is-connect-using-mq-front. Another one: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-websphere-datapower-soa-appliance-mq-manager-objects-connections-are-not-closed-expected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connections that datapower is using are MQI connections (ie client connecting to a SVRCONN channel) you can try setting a disconnect interval on the SVRCONN channel that is being used by datapower. This forces connections that haven't been used for the specified interval to close.

The MQSC command to alter the interval would be this:

```
ALTER CHANNEL(channel_name) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DISCINT(number_of_seconds)
```

Further information about DISCINT is available at the IBM Knowledge Center:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081860_.htm